# Inheritance and method overloading

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, overriding

Why C++ compiler gives this error? Why i can access lol() from B, but can not access rofl() [without parameters]. Where is the catch?

```
class A
{
public:
   void lol(void) {}
   void rofl(void) { return rofl(0);}
   virtual void rofl(int x) {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   virtual void rofl(int x) {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
   a.lol();
   a.rofl(1);
   a.rofl();

   B  b;
   b.lol();
   b.rofl(1);    
   b.rofl(); //ERROR -> B::rofl function does not take 0 arguments


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `B::rofl(int)` 'hides' the `A::rofl()`.  In order to have `A`'s `rofl` overloads, you should declare `B` to be `using A::rofl;`.

```
class B : public A {
public: 
    using A::rofl;
    ...
};
```

This is a wise move of C++: it warns you that you probably also need to override the `A::rofl()` method in `B`.  Either you do that, or you explicitly declare that you use `A`'s other overloads.

Comment: yep, but A::rofl() is not virtual. Thats the idea - rofl() allways calls virtual rofl(0).

Comment: @0xDEAD BEEF: in that case, you _intend_ to use it, so make that clear to the compiler by saying `using A::rofl;`.

Comment: @0xDEAD BEEF: btw, you are creating a 'non-virtual interface'  this way; you probably want your `A::rofl(int)` to be pure virtual, and protected.

Comment: No. I want to crate pure virtual Read(buffer, size, timeout), and wrapper (override) Read(buffer, size) { Read(buffer, size, 0);}
BTW - using keyword works great!

Comment: `@xtofl` with such method names, the question was cut out for you :p