# Polymorphism in C++ why is this isn't working?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual void f();
    void f(int);
    virtual ~Base();
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void f();
};

int main()
{
    Derived *ptr = new Derived;
    ptr->f(1);
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

ptr->f(1); is showing the following error: "too many arguments in function call".

Why is this isn't possible? isn't derived inherited all the functions form base and is free to use any of them?
I could call it explicitly and it would work but why isn't this allowed?

Comment: `f(int)` is not overloaded in `derived`, what do you expect?

Comment: For polymorphism, `ptr` should be a pointer to the *base* class.

Comment: But shouldn't Derived inherit the Base functions? or it's not working with pointers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance and method overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973976/inheritance-and-method-overloading)

Comment: I think I understand now, the derived class has access to function just not in main right?

Comment: It was just for an example, I will edit it in order for the code to be properly written.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are seeing is called *hiding*.

When you override the function `void f()` in the `Derived` class, you *hide* all other variants of the `f` function in the `Base` class.

You can solve this with the `using` keyword:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::f;  // Pull all `f` symbols from the base class into the scope of this class

    void f() override;  // Override the non-argument version
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Some Programming Dude : it is because of Hiding.

To understand hiding in relatively simpler language

`Inheritance` is meant to bring `Base`class variables / functions in `Derived` class.

But, on 1 condition : "If its not already available in Derived Class"

Since `f()` is already available in `Derived`, it doesn't make sense to look at `Base` class from compiler perspective.

That's the precise reason why you need to scope clarify while calling this function

```
void main()
    {
        Derived *ptr = new Derived;
        ptr->Base::f(1);
        delete ptr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for time being that `Derived` do have the access to the function `void Base::f(int);`. Then it will be a case of `function overloading`. But, this is invalid case of `function overloading` since one function `f(int);`is in Base and other function `f();` is in Derived. `Function Overloading` happens inside a single class. `Function Overriding` happens across classes. The example you posted is a case of [Name Hiding in Inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule)

Answer (score 0):

"Derived *ptr" This definition will only allow "ptr" to access all the member functions which are defined via Derived class or its child class. But, it will not allow u to access the member functions which are coming in Derived class because of inheritance.

If u want to access base class version of function "f" then use "Base *ptr" and it will choose the correct version of function automatically as shown :)

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void f()
        {
            cout<<"Here 2"<<endl;
        }
        void f(int x)
        {
            cout<<"Here 1"<<endl;
        }
        virtual    ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        void f()
        {
            cout<<"Here 3"<<endl;
        }
        virtual   ~Derived() {}
};

int main()
{
    Base *ptr = new Derived;
    ptr->f(1);
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

output is 
Here 1